# Making a jquery name tagger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a name tagger in jquery + php. I have done the PHP part and jquery code is 99% done, but my problem is passing the string to search for after the '@' sign. I currently use a div with contentEditable set to true. From what I see in console log the name variable is indeed @+search string, but the list div will not be populated, I tried running the script manually just to debug and it works, including setting the name variable to one specific letter and it populates the list div. Any tips and suggestions appreciated my code below:

```
$("#chat-message").bind("keyup", function (event) {
    //auto name complete
    var search = $(this).text();
    var searchbox = search.split(search.indexOf('@') + 1);
    var checker = search.substr(search.length - 1); //Checks last charcter inserted if its '@'
    var name = search.match(/@(\w+)/ig);
    console.log(name);
    var dataString = 'searchword=' + name + '&search=yes';
    if (name == '' || checker == " ") {
        $("#display-search").hide();
    } else if (checker === "@") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchy.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#display-search").html(html).show();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What do you see when you visit `searchy.php?searchword=term&search=yes` in a browser?

Comment: thanks for the edit, I see the results I would need, for example if the term was pete, i see a list of all the names LIKE 'pete' as I have set up my db query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `ajax` call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "searchy.php",
    "data": {
        "searchword": name,
        "search": "yes"
    },
    "cache": false,
    "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // log error to browser console
        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    },
    "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#display-search").html(data).show();
    }
});
```

What, if anything, do you see in the console?

**UPDATE**

If you're not seeing anything, AJAX isn't getting called. Try a console log to make sure `checker` actually equals `'@'`.

**UPDATE:**

The fundamental problem you're going to have with your logic is that the AJAX function will only be called when `checker === '@'`. As `checker` is the *last* character that the user typed, `name` will never exist when `checker === '@'`.

I would suggest the following logic instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var ajaxIsActivelyPosting = false, // flag to prevent a post on every keyup
        searchForTerm = function searchForTerm(e) {
            //auto name complete
            var search = $(this).text(), //get the text
                matches = search.match(/@(\w+)\s?/ig), // get any matches
                name = matches ? matches : ''; // if there are matches, set the name
            if (name && !ajaxIsActivelyPosting) { // if there's a match, name will be truthy
                $.ajax({
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "searchy.php",
                    "data": {
                        "searchword": name,
                        "search": "yes"
                    },
                    "cache": false,
                    "beforeSend": function (jqXHR, settings) {
                        ajaxIsActivelyPosting = true; //set the flag
                    },
                    "complete": function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        ajaxIsActivelyPosting = false; //clear the flag
                    },
                    "error": function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // log error to browser console, always helpful to have
                        console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                    },
                    "success": function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log(data); //see raw result in browser console
                        $("#display-search").html(data).show();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#display-search').hide();
            }
            return false;
        };
    $('#chat-message').bind('keyup', searchForTerm);
});
```

Comment: I want it to grab text after the '@' is typed, then send that text to the searchy.php file to process then searchy should return some data.

Comment: So, if the user types "kabtuo@", you want the ajax call to happen when the "@" is typed... correct? Also, what is `word`? A regex?

Comment: yes word is the regex I used and i edited my code to add that hehe, I am trying to achieve "@pete" so "@" would be the trigger to start searching for the text that is typed after "@". The console displays the correct data for checker, which is what I used to check for the "@" in the text

Comment: I tried logging the results of search.indexOf("@"); and it keeps returning blank, I think there is the problem but I am totally lost as to why it cant find the '@' symbol

Comment: testing now to see if it is all good, #EDIT thanks alot Pete it worked, and of course its much cleaner show off lol. I need to start making full use of ajax commands.